# Angular 4 click event using data from observable

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I have a smart component, with some data being selected from the store with

```
this.user$ = store.select(fromRoot.getUser)
```

A child component emits up to the smart component off the back of a button click. Inside this event handler (in the smart component), I want to use the value the value of

```
this.user$
```

My only thought is to pass down

```
user$ | async
```

into the dumb and to then emit the user back up with the click event. Is this the best approach?

Comment: Yes, this is how unidirectional data flow works

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too, if you don't wan't to pass the observable with the async pipe:

```
public user: any;
this.user$.subscribe(user => this.user = user);
```

Then you can pass this.user, and not the observable.

But your approach is perfect. This is just an alternative.

Comment: Note: With this approach you should also unsubscribe in OnDestroy.

Comment: @amu Indeed. I commonly create an abstract class to add all the "common" observables, create a little array of subs and then destroy them when I don't need them anymore.